# Developer Story: Issues with Import from GitHub Projects

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

1. When I import a GitHub opensource project into my Developer Story it brings in the project description, but not the topics (which would go nicely into technology section as keywords)
2. It seems the Classic View has no UI to add more items and you have to do it at the Story view which isn't exactly obvious
3. I think when I update a project's start time it goes to top of dev story timeline and it goes to correct place when I refresh the page (haven't tried this extensively)
4. When I import a new project from GitHub I'd expect it to show up in edit mode, not just be added somewhere out of the current view
5. Import UI for GitHub projects has just Add buttons, not Update buttons for already added projects. Having multiple GitHub projects I can't remember which ones I've added and check if I've missed any. Also, there seems to be no action to add all projects. Regarding suggestion 4 above, obviously when doing Add all it shouldn't try to jump into edit mode for each one of the added projects, but if doing Update for a single project it should go into edit mode for it after updating I guess.
6. I think it gets as start time of a project the date the repo was created on GitHub, and not the date of the first commit in the repo. This results in wrong start date for project if the repo was offline initially and then put on GitHub, or even worse if the repo was imported say from CodePlex that is shutting down into GitHub. Haven't tested this extensively, but from some projects that I imported I think that is the case

Comment: regarding 5, I got a little confused since I had projects at "zoomicon" organization in GitHub and forks in my "birbilis" account, so when I told it to import github projects I gave "zoomicon" whereas in the past I had given "birbilis". Thing is I see no "Update" button (and "Update all"), nor "Import all" that I remember it had in the past